# Algorithm for detecting hand

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm conducting research now on ASL hand recognition in real time using Opencv for my thesis (I'm a beginner). Others say that the first thing to do is detecting the hand, so I want to know what is the best algorithm(s)(haar,hsv,background subtraction,etc.) for detecting a hand (a little simple algo would be best for a novice like me =)). Also, can you help me in finding a training ground or should I say an UNDERSTANDABLE tutorial(s) and program(s) for my project??

Comment: Are you using OpenCV in C++, Python or Java?

Comment: c++ sir, and currently using opencv2.4.3

Answer (score 2):

I would start from Haar cascade classifier (V&J algorithm):

http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

Comment: may i ask if Haar cascade classifier can be the best thing to do for my project??

Comment: @Azrael Only you can know what is best for your project. Note that machine recognition of sign language is a very hard problem that hasn't been fully solved yet, so remember to keep realistic project goals.

Comment: You can also use other cascade classifier (LBP for example). 

However, I am familiar with a different project that used Haar cascade for hand detection and got good results.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing some skin detection first to help filter out the background (e.g. using back projection http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html). You could use Haar-like features after that. It sounds quite difficult though.